# how to send array of values to a query dynamically in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

The code in model is
public function get_report6_8($type, $filter_id=NULL) {
    $values = array($filter_id);

```
$select = '';       
if ($filter_id && $type == 'jh') {
    $select = 'and natbuild_rep.jh_rep_id = ?';
}
else if ($filter_id && $type == 'natbuild') {
    $select = 'and natbuild_principal.id = ?';
}

$sql = "select sum(total) total
    from (
        select value_of_sale total
        from lead
        left join natbuild_rep
        on natbuild_rep.mobile = lead.mobile
        left join natbuild_store
        on natbuild_store.id = natbuild_rep.store_id
        left join natbuild_principal
        on natbuild_principal.store_group = ifnull(natbuild_store.store_group2, natbuild_store.store_group)
        where (status = 1 OR status = 2)
        and value_of_sale is not null
        {$select}
        group by lead.id
    ) temp";

return $this->db->query($sql, $values)->row();
}
```

The code in controller is 
$data['report8'] = $this->lead_report_model->get_report6_8($type, $this->input->post('filter'));

code in view is

Grand Total: $total)) ? $report8->total: 0;?>

if I run query like

```
select sum(total) total

from (

    select value_of_sale total
    from lead
    left join natbuild_rep
    on natbuild_rep.mobile = lead.mobile
    left join natbuild_store
    on natbuild_store.id = natbuild_rep.store_id
    left join natbuild_principal
    on natbuild_principal.store_group = ifnull(natbuild_store.store_group2, natbuild_store.store_group)
where (status = 1 OR status = 2)
    and value_of_sale is not null
    and natbuild_principal.id in (18, 30, 31, 35, 33, 25, 23, 15, 8, 6, 5, 29, 7, 3, 2, 1, 24, 27, 22, 21, 20, 26, 36)
group by lead.id ) temp
```

the result is right. please help how can I send array of values to the $select. This happens when I select grand total from a dropdown which contains all other values up there.

Answer (score 0):

your dropdown is multiselect so it will pass an array with the values.

use

```
 implode(",", $dropdownSelections);

 $select = 'and natbuild_principal.id in ('.implode(",", $dropdownSelections).')';
```

Comment: thanks. it worked, but I have to add code before this to capture the key values in an array from the data post array. I did it like this.

Comment: public function get_report6_10($type, $data) {
  $dropdownSelections = array();
  foreach ($data['filter'] as $key => $value) {
   if ($key != ''){
   array_push($dropdownSelections, $key);
   }
  } 
  $dropdownSelections = implode(",", $dropdownSelections);
$select = '';  
    if ( $type == 'natbuild') {
     $select = 'and natbuild_principal.id in ('.$dropdownSelections.')';
    }
    //echo $select;